# Advanced Programming in the Unix Envinronment 3rd, 4.21, I want to how rmdir deal with link count

Tags: linux, filesystems

I read about this in APUE 3rd, 4.21:
If one or more processes have the directory open when the link count reaches 0, the last link is removed and the dot and dot-dot entries are removed before this function returns.
I just can't understand this, I think the "link count reaches 0" should be "link count reaches 2", a empty directory have at least 2 link count. What I want to know is how rmdir deal with link count?

Comment: Looks like `.` and `..` are really removed,see: `mkdir /tmp/TESTD; cd  /tmp/TESTD; ls -la .; rmdir /tmp/TESTD; ls -la .;` The last `ls` does not show the dots. Interestingly the dot still worked as argument for `ls`.

Comment: @rudimeier, another confusion,ls -la .. works correctly.

Comment: And even `ls -la ./.` :)

Comment: @rudimeier, do you know someone who may konw the anwser?Just invite him or her please, thanks.

Comment: No, the empty directory does have 0 link count.  `ls -ld .` ->
`drwxrwxr-x. 0 alan alan 0 Oct 20 20:01`

Comment: I believe the access to `.` is synthesized by the VFS rather than using the "real" file.  I suspect ext4 still creates the on-disk entries for historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused.  `rmdir` simply doesn't care about link counts.  The logic is quite straightforward.

Once a file has a *link count* of 0, and additionally, no running processes with a reference (file descriptor or current directory), it will be truly deleted.  That's the point when the disk space can be re-used for something else [*].

Directories are a file.  But unlinking (removing them from their parent) requires more consideration than other types of file.  We must make sure each child of the directory is unlinked as well.  Otherwise, we could lose the chance to update the children's link count.  We would lose that disk space permanently.

So we don't let users call `unlink` on a directory.  Instead, they must use the special-purpose `rmdir`.  Calling `rmdir` differs from `unlink` in just two ways

1. It requires that the directory is "empty", which means that its only children are the standard `.` and `..` entries.
2. It makes sure to unlink these two remaining entries, before it runs `unlink` on the directory itself.

That's *it*.  There is no other magic.  `rmdir` is not deferred until the condition in point 1 holds.  `rmdir` either succeeds or fails at the time it is called.  Nor is the condition based on link count in any way.

---

I find the effect of the `.` entry on link counts interesting, even though it's not a special case.  It's a hard-link to the parent directory, and therefore increases it's link count.  This is the explanation for why a newly created directory DIR has a link count of 2.  If you then call `rmdir DIR`, the link count falls back to 0, because it removes both links `DIR/.` and `DIR`.

---

Linux actually allows you to observe the above by running a shell inside the directory, and running `ls -ld` after the directory has been unlinked (removed from its parent).

Of course `ls -ld` is shorthand for `ls -ld .`.  `.` and `..` keep working even after the directory entry is removed; in fact modern Linux does not really rely on these on-disk directory entries.  I expect the original Unix implementation would *not* support this.  However I believe the reference counts still worked as described above, and did not have a special-case for the removal of a directory.

(How `..` continues to work is even more interesting.  Discussed in comment below).

In fact it would be very easy for you to look at the original Unix code for `rmdir`.  It was [implemented as a user program running with special privileges](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.minix/paKhZZWixEE).  Historical unix code is easy to find online.  It's one reason I'm so confident about this.

---

[*] So you can see whether a file has been deleted by looking for a difference in used disk blocks in `df .` (or i-nodes in `df -i .`).  This approach works nicely in filesystems like Linux `ext4`.  Less traditional filesystems may have more complex optimizations though, which can make it harder to observe.

Comment: Could you please explain "pathname has .. as its final component"?

Comment: `rmdir TEST1/TEST2/..` will fail.  I don't know why this is specified explicitly though.

Comment: ah, if you look at the context I think it's more to specify which error code happens in this case (ENOTEMPTY).  If the last component is `.`, the error code is EINVAL.

Comment: ok, thanks, even though I don't know when the . or .. will be the final component of a directory, rmdir . or rmdir .. will never succeed, thank anyway. Another confusion, mkdir mytest, cd mytest ,rm ../mytest, then ls -al .. will work correctly, why?

Comment: hah, yes, the answer that it is synthesized by the VFS doesn't entirely explain that.  The answer involves the VFS "dentry" object, holding a reference to its parent dentry.  Each dentry must also hold a reference to the inode, so the parent will stay alive even if it too is unlinked.  Easy way to see this lifetime issue is to look at the destructor :). http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/dcache.c?v=4.7#L767

Comment: BTW I notice I'm conflating unix in general with linux.  I think the fact that '.' and '..' keep working is an artefact of linux support for filesystems that don't have physical directory entries for them.  Give you 90% odds the initial unix code didn't behave that way :).

Comment: There's still a bit of a special case in that the `.` link is removed when it's the only one left. If it wasn't removed, the directory should still have a link count of one, with only a reference from itself... The [wording in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html) is a bit odd to my mind:  _"If one or more processes have the directory open when the last link is removed, the dot and dot-dot entries, if present, shall be removed"_. It's as if the dot entry doesn't count as a "link" here. But I don't know how to read the spec to interpret that.

Comment: no!  I tried to correct you before but ended up removing it.  I'll update my answer.